# On a Lightning Web Component, build arrays of stages for each Opportunity Record Type

Tags: apex, soql, record-type, stagename, businessprocess

I want to generate arrays of Stages for each Opportunity Record Type. The association is really between Stages and Sales Processes but each Opportunity Record Type is related to one Sales Process.

First, I get the list of record types...

```
public class Utility {
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static Map<String, Object> getEnv() {
    Map<String, Object> env = new Map<String, Object>();
    env.put('opportunityRecordTypes', [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Opportunity' AND IsActive = true ORDER BY Name]);
    return env;
  }
}
```

In my Lightning Web Component (LWC)...

```js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import getEnv from '@salesforce/apex/Utility.getEnv';
import STAGE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';

export default class Setup extends LightningElement {
    @track config = {};
    @track error;
    @track recordTypeIds = [];
    currentRecordTypeId;

    @wire(getEnv)
    wiredEnv({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.config = { ...data };
            this.recordTypeIds = data.opportunityRecordTypes.map(rt => rt.Id);
            this.processRecordTypes();
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.config = {};
        }
    }

    processRecordTypes() {
        if (this.recordTypeIds.length > 0) {
            this.currentRecordTypeId = this.recordTypeIds.shift();
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$currentRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: STAGE_FIELD })
    wiredStages({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.updateRecordTypeStages(this.currentRecordTypeId, data.values);
            this.processRecordTypes();
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

    updateRecordTypeStages(recordTypeId, stages) {
        const formattedStages = stages.map(stage => ({
            name: stage.label,
            closed: stage.attributes.closed,
            won: stage.attributes.won,
            forecast: stage.attributes.forecastCategoryName,
            probability: stage.attributes.defaultProbability
        }));

        let recordTypeIndex = this.config.opportunityRecordTypes.findIndex(rt => rt.Id === recordTypeId);
        if (recordTypeIndex >= 0) {
            let opportunityRecordTypesCopy = [...this.config.opportunityRecordTypes];
            opportunityRecordTypesCopy[recordTypeIndex] = {
                ...opportunityRecordTypesCopy[recordTypeIndex],
                stages: formattedStages
            };
            this.config = {
                ...this.config,
                opportunityRecordTypes: opportunityRecordTypesCopy
            };
        }
    }

    get configJson() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.config, null, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you'll have to use the Metadata API to get the `BusinessProcess` object and pull the `values` list.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_businessprocess.htm?q=businessprocess